# Let $X=\Bbb R$ endowed with the finite complement topology $T$. Is $X$ compact with respect to $T$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X=\Bbb R$ endowed with the finite complement topology $T$. Is $X$ compact with respect to $T$?

Let $\{ T_a \}$ be an open cover. Let $[a,b]$ with the usual topology and $X$ be $[a,b]$ with the finite complement topology.

Let any single element of the cover $T_{a_0}$. The complement has finitely elements so there are only finitely many elements of $X$.

$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$,... , $x_n$ are not in this set and $T_{a_i}$ containing $x_i$ so that $X$ is a compact space with resect to $T$.

This is what I have but I'm unsure on correctness so would like to have it checked, please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The $[a,b]$ seems irrelevant. You want to show $X=\Bbb R$ to be compact, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is correct but the proof is badly written. I  have no idea what $[a,b]$ is doing here. Here is a neat way of writing the proof: let $(U_i)$ be an open cover. Then $0 \in U_k$ for some $k$. Let $\mathbb R \setminus U_k =\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. Pick $i_1,i_2,..,i_n$ such that $a_j \in U_{i_j}$. Then $U_k$ together with $U_{i_j}, 1 \leq j \leq n$ is a finite subcover.

Comment: Accidentally typed a second answer instead of editing the first one. My cursor keeps jumping. So please don't complain $ \ddot \smile$